# text files printing issues python/spider

Tags: python, web-crawler, text-files

i am trying to print => "programmer" using textfile but my code is only printing =>mer, gram, pro
my textfile has only the lines : mer, gram, pro
would anybody know what is happening here? i really thought i could manipulate those words and print stg different but i am not sure what is happening here... just wondering if python changed some syntax or python/spider needs different code lines... thanks in advance!

```
infile = open("Dev.txt", 'r')
dev = [line.rstrip() for line in infile]
infile.close()
dev[0], dev[-1] = dev[-1], dev[0]
word = ("").join(dev)
print(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("Dev.txt", 'r') as file:
    dev = file.read().strip().split(",")[::-1]
    word = "".join([i.strip() for i in dev])
    print(word)
```

One liner

```
with open("Dev.txt", 'r') as file:
    print("".join([i.strip() for i in file.read().strip().split(",")[::-1]])
```

Comment: Better than my answer, but you should probably delete the third line and replace `dev` with `dev[::-1]` at the fourth.

Comment: Looks good to me, should be answering the question.